# Solve the following system of differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Let $A = (a_{ij}\in M_3(R))$ be a real matrix and let $P:= \begin{pmatrix}
0 &1  &0 \\ 
0 &1 &1 \\ 
1 &1  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$

such that $P^{-1}AP = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &0 \\ 0 &2 &1 \\ 0 &0 &2 \end{pmatrix} =B$

Let $y_i = y_i(x) (1 \leq i\leq3)$ be differentiable functions in $x$. Solve the following system of differential equations.

$Y' = \begin{pmatrix} y_{1}' \\ y_{2}' \\y_{3}' \end{pmatrix} = AY = A\begin{pmatrix} y_{1} \\ y_{2} \\y_{3} \end{pmatrix}$

1.) I define a linear map $T:R^{3}\rightarrow R^{3}$ where $T(x) = Ax, x\in R^3$

2.) I went about to compute $A = PBP^{-1}$

3.) I attempt to diagonalize $A$, I found that its characteristic polynomial to be $(1 - \lambda)(\lambda - 2)^2 = 0$

4.) with that I proceed to compute the eigen-basis, but thats where I got stuck, there is only 1 eigen-vector for $E_{\lambda = 2}$, but the mulplicity is 2, hence I'm expecting 2 vectors instead of 1.

Which means my approach is wrong somewhere, any help or insight in this is deeply appreciated.

Comment: The matrix is in Jordan canonical form, you also have a generalized eigenvalue. You can still solve this using the exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the differential equation
$$
Y'=AY=PBP^{-1}Y.
$$
Introduce $U=P^{-1}Y$ (that is $Y=PU$) and you have
$$
U'=P^{-1}Y'=P^{-1}PBP^{-1}Y=BU.
$$
Thanks to the simple form of $B$ you can solve $U'=BU$ easily by inspection. You have the equations
$$
u_1'=u_1,\quad u_2'=2u_2+u_3,\quad u_3'=2u_3.
$$
Solve the first ant the third equation (that should be easy). Insert and solve the middle one. Finally, you get $Y$ from $Y=PU$.